# How to migrate from Windows 7 to Windows 10 double bootcamp boot on Macbook late 2011 - MacOS High Sierra

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I am running from long time windows 7 on double boot with bootcamp on a Macbook late 2011 i5 with MacOS High Sierra 4Gb mem.
Due to discontinuation of win 7 support I wish to migrate to win 10.
I read some similar questions but I get confused and, therefore, I ask for HELP.
Thank a lot
Dino Vitale

Comment: We can only answer specific questions. You need to say what port of a similar question you don't understand

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, If you have a Macbook running a "**genuine**" copy of Windows 7/8/8.1 (properly licensed and activated), you can follow the same steps I did to upgrade it to Windows 10.

**Boot your MacBook from your Windows 7 and carry the steps:**

To get started, go to the [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows10) webpage and click the **Download tool now** button. After the download completes, run the Media Creation Tool.

[image]

Choose the Upgrade this PC now option and be done with it.

Then just follow the prompts to complete the upgrade. You will not be asked for a product key, and when the upgrade is complete and you've connected to the Internet, you'll have a digital license to Windows 10, which you can confirm by going to **Settings > Update & Security > Activation.**

The digital license is associated with that specific device, which means you can reformat the disk and perform a clean installation of the same edition of Windows 10 anytime. You won't need a product key, and activation is automatic.

Comment: And just for an extra comment - if you will be asked for a product key, then just use the Windows 7 product key, this key can also be used on any install, on any PC - if you would want to do this.

Comment: Also note that Apple does not officially support Windows 10 on that Mac. That means that some things may not work because Apple does not have updated drivers (officially) for Windows 10 on that Mac. People have been successful doing this but it may require a bit of fiddling and/or putting up with things that don't work.